# Javascript integration with CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I'm currently integrating this javascript code provided by another website
They gave me this code to put on my website

```
<object class="gm_ref_rates">
  <param name="size" value="small">
  <param name="metal" value="silver">
  <param name="currency" value="USD">
  <param name="currency_dropdown" value="show">
  <param name="language" value="en">

 </object>
```

I'm beginning in javascript and I have no idea how to change the appearence CSS class are not working with this object. I should put just the text in a horizontal line
Any link help or explaination will be very appreciated

Comment: If this is a plugin of some kind, then you are out of luck tuning its appearance with CSS. At best, it should be configurable through the `object` `param`s.

Comment: thank you may be I should take directly the source of the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a very localised question but the source is here

http://www.goldmoney.com/js/gm_ref_rates.js

and you need to change the

`affiliate_chart` class, but that is likely only possible to change that if you become an affiliate

http://www.goldmoney.com/affiliate-charts.html

does not have the means to change the CSS

Comment: I'm an affiliate so I tried to put the js directly in my website but I have an error memory

Comment: Did you fix it? It works for me